# addIceCandidate with argument null result in error

Tags: javascript, webrtc, rtcpeerconnection

I am trying to learn WebRTC, I had achieved connecting two RTCPeerConnection in same page and I am now attempting to separate them into two separate pages and connects them.
However, after code are written and exchanged offer and answer, I noticed addIceCandidate() on initiator.html will always throw this with null argument

`Error at addIceCandidate from queue:  TypeError: Failed to execute 'addIceCandidate' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Candidate missing values for both sdpMid and sdpMLineIndex
    at processCandidateQueue (initiator.html:69)`

After some reading, I learnt null is used to indicate ICE Candidate gathering finishes and example here: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/pc1/
Also executes "addIceCandidate" with argument null when gathering finishes.
But I do not understand why I am seeing the error I see at this moment.

What I had tried:

1. I had tried to write a check such that if candidate is null, skip addIceCandidate.
2. Place all connection logic in less buttons to reduce delay between function calls
3. Add adapter-latest.js to each page

Result:

1. Initiator connection state is "fail", receiver connection state is "new". Failed to stream to receiver page.
2. Same error was thrown
3. Error is gone, but connection still fails

initiator.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>First WebRTC Project</title>
        <link href="common.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
        <div class="log-display"></div>
        <div class="func-list">
            Initiating host
            <div class="func">
                <button onclick="onPrepareMedia(this)">Prepare media</button>
                <video class="dump"></video>
            </div>
            <div class="func">
                <button onclick="onCreatePeerConnection(this)">onCreatePeerConnection()</button>
                <textarea class="dump"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="func">
                <button onclick="onCreateOffer(this)">onCreateOffer()</button>
                <textarea class="dump"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="func">
                <button onclick="onSetLocalDescription(this)">onSetLocalDescription()</button>
                <textarea class="dump"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="func">
                <button onclick="onSetRemoteDescription(this, answerReceived)">onSetRemoteDescription() // set answerReceived variable manually</button>
                <textarea class="dump"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="common.js"></script>
        <script>
            localStorage.removeItem("FirstWebRTC_offer");
            localStorage.removeItem("FirstWebRTC_answer");
            var constraints = { video: true, audio: true };
            var stream = null;
            var peerConn = null;
            var offer = null, offerReceived = null;
            var answer = null, answerReceived = null;
            const offerOptions = {
                offerToReceiveAudio: 1,
                offerToReceiveVideo: 1
            };

            candidateQueue = [];
            var onIceCandidate = async function(e) {
                window.log("onIceCandidate", e);
                if(peerConn.remoteDescription) {
                    var rslt = e.candidate && await peerConn.addIceCandidate(e.candidate).catch(e => onError("addIceCandidate", e));
                } else {
                    candidateQueue.push(e.candidate);
                }
                window.log(JSON.stringify(rslt));
            };
            var onIceConnectionStateChange = function(e) {
                window.log("onIceConnectionStateChange", e);
            };
            var onNegotiationNeeded = function(e) {
                console.log("-----", e);
            }

            var processCandidateQueue = async function() {
                for(var i in candidateQueue) {
                    var candidate = candidateQueue[i];
                    await peerConn.addIceCandidate(candidate).catch(e => onError("addIceCandidate from queue", e));
                }
            }

            async function onPrepareMedia(e) {
                stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
                e.parentElement.children[1].value = dumpProperty(stream)
                video = e.parentElement.children[1];
                video.srcObject = stream;
                video.play();
            }

            function onCreatePeerConnection(e) {
                peerConn = new RTCPeerConnection({});

                // Setup ICE event handlers
                peerConn.onicecandidate = onIceCandidate;
                peerConn.oniceconnectionstatechange = onIceConnectionStateChange;
                peerConn.onnegotiationneeded = onNegotiationNeeded

                // Add tracks to be transmitted
                stream.getTracks().forEach(track => peerConn.addTrack(track, stream));

                e.parentElement.children[1].value = dumpProperty(peerConn)
            }

            async function onCreateOffer(e) {
                offer = await peerConn.createOffer(offerOptions)
                localStorage.setItem("FirstWebRTC_offer", JSON.stringify(offer))
                e.parentElement.children[1].value = dumpProperty(offer)
            }

            async function onSetLocalDescription(e) {
                var rslt = await peerConn.setLocalDescription(offer)
                e.parentElement.children[1].value = dumpProperty(rslt)
            }

            async function onSetRemoteDescription(e) {
                answerReceived = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("FirstWebRTC_answer"));
                rslt = await peerConn.setRemoteDescription(answerReceived)
                e.parentElement.children[1].value = dumpProperty(rslt)
                processCandidateQueue();
            }
        </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

receiver.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>First WebRTC Project</title>
        <link href="common.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
        <div class="log-display"></div>
        <div class="func-list">
            Receiving host
            <div class="func">
                <button >Received video</button>
                <video class="dump"></video>
            </div>
            <div class="func">
                <button onclick="onCreatePeerConnection(this)">onCreatePeerConnection()</button>
                <textarea class="dump"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="func">
                <button onclick="onSetRemoteDescription(this)">onSetRemoteDescription()</button>
                <textarea class="dump"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="func">
                <button onclick="onCreateAnswer(this)">onCreateAnswer()</button>
                <textarea class="dump"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="func">
                <button onclick="onSetLocalDescription(this)">onSetLocalDescription()</button>
                <textarea class="dump"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="common.js"></script>
        <script>
            localStorage.removeItem("FirstWebRTC_offer");
            localStorage.removeItem("FirstWebRTC_answer");
            var constraints = { video: true, audio: true };
            var stream = null;
            var peerConn = null;
            var offer = null, offerReceived = null;
            var answer = null, answerReceived = null;
            const offerOptions = {
                offerToReceiveAudio: 1,
                offerToReceiveVideo: 1
            };

            var onTrack = function(e) {
                console.log(e);
                video = document.querySelector("video")
                if (video.srcObject !== e.streams[0]) {
                    video.srcObject = e.streams[0];
                    video.play();
                    console.log('received and playing remote stream');
                }
            }

            var onIceCandidate = async function(e) {
                window.log("onIceCandidate", e);
                var rslt = e.candidate && await peerConn.addIceCandidate(e.candidate).catch(e => onError("addIceCandidate", e));
                window.log(JSON.stringify(rslt));
            };
            var onIceConnectionStateChange = function(e) {
                window.log("onIceConnectionStateChange", e);
            };

            function onCreatePeerConnection(e) {
                peerConn = new RTCPeerConnection({});

                // Setup ICE event handlers
                peerConn.onicecandidate = onIceCandidate;
                peerConn.oniceconnectionstatechange = onIceConnectionStateChange;
                peerConn.ontrack = onTrack;

                e.parentElement.children[1].value = dumpProperty(peerConn);
            }

            async function onSetRemoteDescription(e) {
                offerReceived = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("FirstWebRTC_offer"));
                rslt = await peerConn.setRemoteDescription(offerReceived);
                e.parentElement.children[1].value = dumpProperty(rslt);
            }

            async function onCreateAnswer(e) {
                answer = await peerConn.createAnswer(offerReceived);
                localStorage.setItem("FirstWebRTC_answer", JSON.stringify(answer));
                e.parentElement.children[1].value = dumpProperty(answer);
            }

            async function onSetLocalDescription(e) {
                var rslt = await peerConn.setLocalDescription(answer);
                e.parentElement.children[1].value = dumpProperty(rslt);
            }
        </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

common.js

```
function dumpProperty(obj, noJSON) {
    var output = JSON.stringify(obj);
    if(output == "{}" || noJSON) {
        output = ""
        for (var property in obj) {
            output += property + ': ' + obj[property]+';\n';
        }
    }
    return output;
}

function onError(name, e) {
    console.warn("Error at " + name + ": ", e);
}

window.log = function(str, obj) {
    var logDisplay = document.getElementsByClassName('log-display')[0];
    if(logDisplay) {
        var newLog = document.createElement("div");
        newLog.innerText = str + " : " + dumpProperty(obj);
        logDisplay.appendChild(newLog);
    }
    console.log(str, obj);
}
```

common.css

```
.connection-flow-diagram {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
}
.func-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.func {
    padding: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: 1px dashed black;
}
.func button {

}
.func .dump {
    height: 180px;
}
.log-display {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    pointer-events: none;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @jib why does supplying addIceCandidate with null will result in error while the example code works fine.

Comment: What browser (and version) are you getting this error from? Note your `onIceCandidate` function is totally busted, calling `addIceCandidate` on itself.

Comment: Your code is also queing ICE candidates, which is complicated and [unnecessary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36851163/918910).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does supplying addIceCandidate with null result in error while the example code works fine?

It's because your browser is not up to spec. 
`addIceCandidate(null)` is valid in the [latest spec](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#idl-def-rtcpeerconnection), and indistinguishable from `addIceCandidate()` and `addIceCandidate({})`. They all signal end-of-candidates from the remote end.

The [WebRTC samples](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/pc1/) work because they use [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtcHacks/adapter), which polyfills the correct spec behavior on older browsers.

Answer (score -1):

After some reading, I had figured out why my code does not work. It contains a fatal flaw that is unrelated to the title of this question.

First, answer the question of title.
Q"Why does supplying addIceCandidate() with null will result in error?"
A: This is because I had read an out-dated article on WebRTC, where some time in the past addIceCandidate() was able to take a null value and it will be happy. However, as of 2019 April 25th, this is no longer the case. Instead, with current implemetation:

> If the event's candidate property is null, ICE gathering has finished.

[MDN - Event: RTCPeer​Connection​.onicecandidate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/onicecandidate)

Therefore, to properly handle this case, I need to test for null candidate

```
onIceCandidateHandler(e)
    if e.candidate is not null
        signalingMedium.sendToRemote(e.candidate)
    else
        do nothing
```

Which is why when I added adapter-latest.js, the error goes away; it replaces addIceCandidate() to guard against null candidate

Second, I mentioned although the error goes away when adapter-latest.js was added.
This is because I was doing signaling the wrong way.

Here is the description of icecandidate event from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/onicecandidate)

> This happens whenever the local ICE agent **needs to deliver a message to the other peer** through the signaling server.
>
> ...
>
> simply implement this method to use whatever messaging technology you choose to **send the ICE candidate to the remote peer**.

Where in my own code, I was adding candidate to local peer connection (which is wrong).

```
var onIceCandidate = async function(e) {
    window.log("onIceCandidate", e);
    if(peerConn.remoteDescription) {
        var rslt = e.candidate && await peerConn.addIceCandidate(e.candidate).catch(e => onError("addIceCandidate", e));
    } else {
        candidateQueue.push(e.candidate);
    }
    window.log(JSON.stringify(rslt));
};
```

Thus connection always fail because I was actually connecting to myself.

I will provide a jsFiddle with corrected code once I fixed the issue.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, in that `addIceCandidate(null)` is actually valid in the [latest spec](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#idl-def-rtcpeerconnection). It's indistinguishable from `addIceCandidate()` and `addIceCandidate({})`.